Nginx => SSL path with variable
Configuring Nginx to Dynamically Include $host in SSL Certificate Paths
How can I configure my server block in Nginx to dynamically incorporate the $host variable into the file paths for SSL certificate and key files?
Here is an example to illustrate the concept:
 server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    set $dynamic_path "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$host/fullchain.pem";
    set $dynamic_path_two "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$host/privkey.pem";
    ssl_certificate $dynamic_path;
    ssl_certificate_key $dynamic_path_two;
    location / { add_header Content-Type application/json; return 200 "halo"; }
}

This is my best attempt.
map $host $ssl_cert_path {
    default "";
    ~^(?<domain>.+)$ "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/fullchain.pem";
}
map $host $ssl_key_path {
    default "";
    ~^(?<domain>.+)$ "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/privkey.pem";
}

server { listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate $ssl_cert_path;
ssl_certificate_key $ssl_key_path;

location / {
    add_header Content-Type application/json;
    return 200 "halo";
}

